# Python, скачиваю аудио через VK_API.Но оно скачивается в формате m3u8. Как конвертировать в mp3?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

```
def vk_music_get(login,password):

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(login=login, password=password)
vk_session.auth(token_only=False)
vk_session.get_api()
vk_aud = vk_api.audio.VkAudio(vk_session)
for i in vk_aud.get():
    print(i)
    music_name = i['artist']
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(i['url'], f'\\Users\\AlexK\\PycharmProjects\\MyArchive\\music_vk\\{music_name}.m3u8  ')
print('VK Download Success! ^_^')
```

Ни в каком другом формате оно не скачивается.

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться библиотекой ffmpeg

```
import vk_api
from vk_api import audio
import os
import re

def vk_music_get(login,password):
    vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(login=login, password=password)
    vk_session.auth(token_only=False)
    vk_session.get_api()
    vk_aud = audio.VkAudio(vk_session)

    for i in vk_aud.get():
        music_name = i['artist']
        music_url = i['url']
        music_name = re.sub(' ', '`', music_name)
        os.system(f'ffmpeg -y -i {music_url} C:\\Users\\lebed\\Desktop\\music\\{music_name}.mp3')

    print('VK Download Success! ^_^')
```

Comment: "ffmpeg" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.
"ffmpeg" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
В консоль выводятся вот такие символы красным цветом, и все. Аудио не сохраняется, но и ошибки не выдает.

Comment: Вы установили [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html)? Также после установки, убедитесь, что ffmpeg добавлен в переменные среды.